# HTML ordered list number still stays on deletion

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to implement functionality which will display a side-view list of items. When clicked on the item, they disappear. I want to have an ordered list where every item has a number (1,2,3..) before it respectively.

html:

```
 <ol type ="1">
    <li *ngFor="let item of getSlices()">
      <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" *ngIf="item.selected">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
  </ol>
```

css:

```
.btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

In my current implementation, the item content disappears on click, but the number (1,2..) in front of the item still stays there.

It works if I add the following class="selection-list" to the  tag and have the following css:

```
.selection-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #555;
  padding-left: 23px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

But in this case, the numbers do not appear at all.

I just want a list like

```
   1. x apple
   2. x banana
   3. x pear
```

Current working if clicked on banana:

```
  1. x apple
  2.
  3. x pear
```

Expected result if clicked on banana:

```
  1. x apple
  2. x pear
```

How can this be done? Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the template using `ng-container` so that non-selected elements won't be rendered at all:

```
<ol type="1">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of getSlices()">
    <li *ngIf="item.selected">
      <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" >
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ol>
```

As it stays, there's a `<li>` element for each item in `getSlices()` - empty for non-selected, but yet present in DOM. That's why there are numbers over there. With this rewrite, you skip those `<li>` completely.